# HTML Form no longer calls Python through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, flask

I was displaying some data from a flask-app via an html table, including a dynamic form in this table:

```
<Table id="Datenbank" width="800px" align="left" >
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Wochentag</th>
        <th>Startzeitpunkt</th>
        <th>Wochentag</th>
        <th>Endzeitpunkt</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Option</th>
        </tr>

        <form method="post" action="/delete_data_via_table">
        {% for element in datatable %}
        <tr>
            <td align="center"> {{ element[0] }} </td>
            <td align="center"> {{ element[5] }} </td>
            <td align="center"> {{ element[4] }} </td>
            <td align="center"> {{ element[7] }} </td>
            <td align="center"> {{ element[6] }} </td>
            <td align="left">   {{ element[1] }} </td>
            <td align="center"><button name="WhichEntryDel" id="WhichEntryDel" value="{{ element[0] }}" type="submit">Entfernen</button></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </form>
</table>
```

The value of the pressed button is transfered to a flask-app called "delete_data_via_table" to delete this row of the database.

I'm now using the jquery.dataTables to display the data:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Datenbank').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

and

```
    <Table id="Datenbank" class="display" width="800px" align="left">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Wochentag</th>
        <th>Startzeitpunkt</th>
        <th>Wochentag</th>
        <th>Endzeitpunkt</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Option</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <form method="post" action="/delete_data_via_table">
        {% for element in datatable %}
        <tr>
            <td align="center"> {{ element[0] }} </td>
            <td align="center"> {{ element[5] }} </td>
            <td align="center"> {{ element[4] }} </td>
            <td align="center"> {{ element[7] }} </td>
            <td align="center"> {{ element[6] }} </td>
            <td align="left">   {{ element[1] }} </td>
            <td align="center"><button name="WhichEntryDel" id="WhichEntryDel" value="{{ element[0] }}" type="submit">Entfernen</button></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </form>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

[Example view of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4figy.jpg)

The problem now is nothing happens if you press that button ... I guess that's because the javascript of the table isn't passing through the information.

Do you have any idea to fix that?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Does it work if you do not use jquery.DataTables?

Comment: Yes, without any problem. I changed later to jquery.DataTables because of the functionality (search-box, sites) and better design.

Comment: Has no one any idea?

Comment: [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html) is an example with a clickable button. You should be able to customize the click callback to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input, my code now looks like this:

Flask-app:

```
@app.route('/_delete_data_via_table_v2')
def delete_data_via_table_v2():
del_ID = request.args.get('a', 0, type=int)
tmp_string = "DELETE FROM ledtext WHERE ID = "+ str(del_ID)
g.db.execute(tmp_string)
g.db.commit()
flash ('Eintrag ' + str(del_ID) + ' erfolgreich gelöscht.')
return jsonify()
```

And HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
moment.locale('de');

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#Datenbank').DataTable( {
        /*"ajax": "data/arrays.txt", */
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button>Entfernen</button>"
        } ]
    } );

    $('#Datenbank tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_delete_data_via_table_v2', { a: data[0] } );
        /* location.reload(true); */
    } );
} );
</script>
```

If you press a button the app is called and the entry is deleted. But the Flash-Information and the table-view changes not before you manually reload the page (pressing F5).

Normally I use this code at the end of an app:

```
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

But it's not working hear. Means: The page isn't rendered again and the flash-information not appears by itself.

Has anyone an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I now solved it with adding "*location.reload(false)*". There may be a better solution.

```
        $('#Datenbank tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_delete_data_via_table_v2', {
            a: data[0]                                              /* Übergibt die ID (als Nummer) */
            }, function(data) {                                     /* Erforderlich für Aktualisierung */
            location.reload(false) });                              /* Verursacht Aktualisierung (false bewirkt abgeschwächte Form des Neuladens) */
            /* return false; */                                     /* Anscheinend überflüssig */
            });
    } );
```